# How can I append text in the middle of a pipeline?

Tags: command-line, shell-script, sh

With `cat` its possible to append a file to the data passing through a pipeline:

```
foo | cat - somefile.txt | bar
```

Is there a command that lets me append text without using an intermediate file?

```
foo | xxx - "contents of somefile" | bar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
{ foo; echo contents not stored in file; } | bar
```

or (almost the same, but starts a subshell):

```
( foo; echo contents not stored in file ) | bar
```

Edit: A totally different approach, closer in design to what you were looking for:

```
foo | cat - <(echo additional contents) | bar
```

See "Process substitution" in bash's manual.